# Differences In Wireless Standards

Tags: wireless

What are the differences between 3g and LTE? I understand the basics, speed and bandwidth etc, but I want to know how the improvements are achieved and where I can read up.

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia pages on both? I mean, this is seriously a large topic, and you can't expect us to write a book just for you

Comment: I have read the Wiki's but I mean just on a basic level, not only those two technologies, what is done to a radio signal to improve it? For expample, is the data just encrypted better, or is the signal produced different?

Comment: That is even broader? How much time do you have? At the uni I'm from, you need to study a couple of years of math, physics, signal theory, wave propagation, network theory and so on to be able to understand that question.

Comment: I understand it would be a long answer. I have a comp sci degree and have read a lot about physics, but every book I've read basically talks about the waves being made of photons and the basic science of radio waves. I have some background, just not the exact real world experience at that level.

Comment: What books and topics would I study at your uni?

Comment: You'd study EE.

Comment: Of course you would study EE. Thats why I am in the EE section here. What books or materials would you look at? Like if someone asked me about Java, in the computer world, Id say read these three O'Reilly books.

Comment: There's a lot of how a radio transceiver system is designed that is far from the electromagnetic wave, and a complete comparison between 3G and LTE is really really something for a PhD thesis, not an answer here. Maybe you'd want to take a step back and understand either system first, and then do the other. You'd need a good basis in signals and system theory (which is pretty math-y), then do a good course digital communications. If you're, in the end, able to read Proakis' book "Digital Communications", you've won, and will be able to understand what 3G and LTE do differently, and why one has

Comment: advantages over the other. Now, I'd really love to answer your questions on the way there – but you need to start smaller.

Comment: Work your way up till you understand how a digital receiver works at all, what baseband, what a constellation is. I think this is something that you might aspire to for now – there's a lot of interesting stuff to be learned on the way. And then, add multi-user, synchronization, channel coding, and a lot of real-world problems.

Comment: Thanks for the book recomendation. I understand what baseband is (not trying to be rude, just saying I get that part). I understand most of the basic terms and science, but a hard time visualizing it in use, if that makes sense. I'm going to order the book.

Comment: That's good news! You're really not coming over as being rude! The book's great, I like it a lot, and you can get older editions cheap used on amazon/abebooks etc. But it's definitely a theory-heavy book.

Comment: I'm also going to check out Fundamentals of Wireless Communication by David Tse unless you think there are better options.

Comment: Tse's an author often recommended to me, so it's probably a good choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple way too broad a question. However, a couple of points could be made.

A primary improvement in LTE is the use of **OFDM** as the modulation scheme. This improves signal quality by mitigating frequency selective fading effects.

LTE also proposes a more improved architecture (eNodeBs etc.) which define an **Internet** based scheme. All voice and data traffic are routed on the Internet i.e. using the IP protocol!

A layman answer to why LTE produces greater data rates is simply owing to the above two reasons, higher bandwidth (more spectrum) and efficient spectrum sharing schemes.

I also want to add that the book Fundamentals of Wireless Communications by Tse and Viswanath treats the subject primarily at the physical layer, and you might want to read other books that look at this topic from a higher layer perspective as well. I would also suggest the website [www.radio-electronics.com](http://www.radio-electronics.com). They've got some simple explanations to the questions you have.

Comment: Nah, OFDM doesn't mitigate fading – it however makes equalizers easier. The IP layer has nothing to do with LTE being better at sharing spectrum; whether you push through IP packets or other packetized data really makes no difference to the MAC layer.

Comment: eNodeB is in fact an architectural enhancement of LTE over 3G over what was planned for the latter as small cell base station. The "e" is for "enhanced". 3G has "Node B"s,which are radio heads that directly connect to a Radio Network Controller that does all the heavy lifting,without much smarts in the Node B. eNodeBs basically have the RNC integrated, which reduces the amount of information that must travel the backend network, and reduces latency. Now, of course, you can literally just put an 3G RNC and 3G Node B in the same box and have functionally the same for 3G – which is commonly done.